# How do I fix this flutter app build error?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

Error that I am facing whenever I try to build my app:

```
`: Error: Type 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' not found.
text_selection.dart:716
  final DragSelectionUpdateCallback? onDragSelectionUpdate;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' isn't a type.
text_selection.dart:716
  final DragSelectionUpdateCallback? onDragSelectionUpdate;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The non-abstract class 'RawEditorState' is missing implementations for these members:
raw_editor.dart:254
 - TextInputClient.insertContent
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class RawEditorState extends EditorState
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Context: 'TextInputClient.insertContent' is defined here.
text_input.dart:1117
  void insertContent(KeyboardInsertedContent content) {}
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/wikijit/flutter_development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/wikijit/flutter_development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited`
```

I figured out this part of the code is causing the error:

```
`
setState(() {
      _controller = QuillController(
          document: doc, selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0));
    });
`
```

I am getting this error while I am trying to build a notes app (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUCCHdKwKxE&t=760s) on flutter, could anyone help me by telling what is this error and how can I fix it?

I followed the steps exactly as mentioned in the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUCCHdKwKxE&t=760s and have reched till creating of adding notes page (around 13:00 in the video) but now the app is not getting built. Prior to creating this when only the home page was made no issues were there while building.

I have also tried running flutter doctor on the terminal but there are no issues present henceforth I am even more confused why is this happening.

I am a complete beginner in flutter app development so if anyone has faced any similar issue or knows any solution please help me with it as I am very much confused as to how I can fix this issue.

Thank You!

Note: I am using VS code for writing the code and have connected my android device using USB debugging to run the app on it for testing.